# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response のエラー表示を消すためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, paypal, cors

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示を願います。

---

#### 【質問の主旨】

[GitHub](https://github.com/echizenyayota/advanced-interactivity-in-amp/tree/developer_liquidation)に公開したコードをローカル開発環境上で実行してPayPalの決済ボタンを押すと、コンソール画面上に下記のエラーが表示されます。

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/xoplatform/logger/api/logger with MIME type text/html.
```

このエラーを表示させないようにするためには、公開したコードのうち、どこをどう修正すれば良いでしょうか？

#### 【質問の補足】

1.

GitHubのコードを実行すると、AMPの公式ドキュメントで示されている[「インタラクティブな AMP ページを作成する」](https://bit.ly/2F2KVJs)というECサイトのチュートリアルが表示されます。PayPalボタン以外の箇所はこのチュートリアルを写経しています。

2.

PayPalの決済ボタンはPayPal developerの[Smart Payment Buttons Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/horizontal)に基づいて作成しました。

3.

ECサイトではありますが、「インタラクティブな AMP ページを作成する」とPayPalの決済ボタンの間に価格などの特別な紐付けをしていません。単にAMPとPayPalで示されているコードを足し合わせただけです。

4.

エラーが発生する理由はCORSのルールにもとづき、オリジンポリシー異なるURLの間でデータの受け渡しをする状態になっていないためだと推測しています。

5.

今回のエラーを表示させないためには、

```
fetch('https://hoge.com/fuga',{
    mode: 'cors'
})
```

のようなコードをどこかに記述すべきだと思いますが、どこに`fetch`メソッドを使った詳細なコードを書くのかよく分かりません。

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

---

**※補足：開発環境（コメントより）**
ローカル開発環境は、Node.jsを使用しています。
`cd advanced-interactivity-in-amp` → `node app.js` → `localhost:3000` で表示画面を確認することができます
https://amp.dev/ja/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/interactivity/prereqs-setup?format=websites
https://github.com/echizenyayota/advanced-interactivity-in-amp/blob/developer_liquidation/app.js#L103-L105

Comment: "ローカルの開発環境"について、どういう環境なのか詳細を記載いただけますか？

Comment: Siegさん。ご指摘ありがとうございます。ローカル開発環境は、Node.jsを使用しています。
`cd advanced-interactivity-in-amp` → `node app.js` → `localhost:3000` で表示画面を確認することができます
https://amp.dev/ja/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/interactivity/prereqs-setup?format=websites
https://github.com/echizenyayota/advanced-interactivity-in-amp/blob/developer_liquidation/app.js#L103-L105